# relation etween image perp and ker transpose

Tags: vector-spaces

I want to show $(\text {im } A)^{\perp}= \ker A^T.$, here is how i tried:
could anyone help me to solve fully.

Let, $x\in (\text{im }A)^{\perp}\Rightarrow \langle x, y\rangle =0\forall y\in \text{im }A\Rightarrow
\langle x, Au\rangle =0\forall Au(=y)$ now does this means $x\in ker A^T$? $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

Let $x \in (Im\  A)^\perp$. Then, we have that $\langle x,Ay\rangle = 0$ for all $y \in V$ (where $V$ is the vector space that is the domain of $A$). Hence, $\langle A^Tx,y\rangle = 0$ for all $y \in V$. This, of course, implies that $A^Tx = 0$, for example by putting $y=A^Tx$, hence $x \in \ker A^T$.

On the other hand, $x \in \ker A^T \implies A^T x = 0 \implies \langle A^Tx,y\rangle = 0\  \forall\  y\in V \\ \implies \langle x,Ay\rangle = 0 \ \forall\ y \in V \implies x \in (Im A)^\perp$

Thus, the given sets are the same.